# track model not being created in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actioncontroller

in my rails app, I am running into an issue. As a heads up I am using devise.

tracks_controller.rb

```
def new
  @track = Track.new
end

def create
  @track = current_user.tracks.build(params[:content])
  if @track.save
    flash[:success] = "Track created!"
    redirect_to @user 
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @tracks = @user.tracks
  if signed_in?
    @track  = current_user.tracks.build
  end
end
```

I am logged in as a current user, and when I try to add a new track (through the current user) it is not saving.. (and instead redirects to root_url)

track.rb

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates :username, uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false }

  has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy

end
```

shared/_track_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@track) do |f| %>
<div class="track_field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Upload a youtube song URL...", :id => "message_area" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

relavent section for /users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="span8">
    <% if signed_in? %>
        <section>
            <%= render 'shared/track_form' %>
        </section>
    <% end %>
```

I believe the issue is in my TracksController #create method, however I just can't figure it out. any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd guess first of all that `params[:content]` should actually be `params[:track][:content]` or something similar, though you should be able to just give it params[:track] unless you have extra fields in your form. Additionally you can use `save!` instead which will raise an exception that might give you more of a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller `create` action change

```
@track = current_user.tracks.build(params[:content])
```

to this

```
@track = current_user.tracks.build(params[:track])
```

Since you used `form_for(@track)` the params hash will contain the `:content` field filled into the form.

The way you have it now the `create` action cant find the form `:content` because there isn't a form named `content`. `content` is an attribute of the `Track` model.

Comment: Thanks for the help - that worked and cleared things up for me -Cheers!